# How do you find the classification/category attribute that is fitted by GaussianMixture from SkLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, gmm, mixture

I have a data with a series of gene expression. I am trying to locate the bimodal distribution and the classification of samples under one or the other fitted Gaussian Distribution. How would you find the classification attribute from the fitted GaussianMixture from SkLearn. It would be like the classification attribute from mclust in r. Thank you!

Comment: If you have some data that you know falls into one of the groups, you can use it to distinguish the two distributions as a kind of implicit labelling when it's over a threshold and/or argmax

Comment: So what attribute would you look it. Is there a probability attribute? Thank you!